# Deploying .NET application on AWS

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my .NET application on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk.
The application contains multiple projects. These projects are mapped to different child directories under a common parent directory in IIS.

The AWS ToolKit for Visual Studio allows one to publish one project at a time.
How can I have multiple projects packaged together and then deployed ?

I'm new to AWS, would really appreciate any help !

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible from the VS plugin. We have a slightly different setup where we have a IIS project and a normal console project on the same EB instance. In order to install the console project (actually, a Windows Service), we use the [.ebextensions](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/Tx1RLX98N5ERPSA/Customizing-Windows-Elastic-Beanstalk-Environments-Part-1) structure to download the package from S3 and execute a script to install it every time we deploy the web application.

In your case, it could be similar; your build script deploys all web apps to S3 (Zip files) and then you install them using the .ebextensions structure. But I haven't really tried that with Web projects, so I don't know how your script would look like.

You may want to consider the CodeDeploy AWS service for your situation. Elastic Beanstalk is really oriented towards one-environment-one-project (which per se is not really wrong).

Answer (score 1):

There is no microsoft plugin available, however Amazon has a Visual Studio Application Deployment task at moment.

There are a AWS solution called CodeDeploy:
[image]
[Visual Studio Team Services - AWS CodeDeploy Application Deployment task](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/deploying-net-web-applications-using-aws-codedeploy-with-visual-studio-team-services/) 
Available to download on [GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-vsts-tools) and [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-vsts-tools)

Other alternatives of automation, you may choose one AWS frameworks available like Claudia, APEX, Serverless. An another alternative is [serverless framework](https://serverless.com).

The serverless framework in junction of an [EB plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-elastic-beanstalk).

With this alternative you can easily define the module deployment on the serverless.yml file and deploy using command line.

```
provider:
...

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-elastic-beanstalk

custom:
  elastic-beanstalk:
    variables:
enter your EB definitions here
```

And run using

```
sls deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that works, albeit using further resources, is to create an Elastic Beanstalk environment for Windows by using the sample code provided, then making an EC2 server instance for Windows from within your EB environment. Then use IIS inside the EC2 instance by connecting remotely with an RDP desktop portal (it is a virtual machine instance). Publish the application solution using IIS like you would locally (zip the app then use your clipboard to c + p it into the RDP portal desktop from your local desktop). It takes some basic networking after that to get the application up to a domain name on the web. There are also a few security benefits to doing it this way if you get a bit creative.